Jackson's derivation for 2D Green's function from 3D Green's function
I'm reading through Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics (3rd Edition), and I'm looking at the derivation of the 2D Green's function from the 3D Green's function at the end of Section 3.11.
Specifically, this equation

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}- \mathbf{x'}|} = \frac{4}{\pi}\int\limits_0^{\infty} \mathrm{d}k \cos[k(z-z')] \times \left\{\frac{1}{2}I_0(k \rho_<)K_0(k \rho_>)+ \sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\cos[m(\phi-\phi')]I_m(k \rho_<)K_m(k \rho_>) \right\}$$

is reduced to the below equation under $z'=0$ at $k \to 0$. More details are in the book.

$$\displaystyle \ln \left(\frac{1}{\rho^2 + \rho'^2-2\rho\rho'\cos(\phi - \phi')}\right) = 2 \ln \left(\frac{1}{\rho_>}\right) + 2\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m}\left(\frac{\rho_<}{\rho_>}\right)^m \cos[m(\phi - \phi')]$$

I understand the math behind the process, but I'm struggling with the physical intuition. What is the physical meaning of $z'=0$ and $k\to 0$?

The limit $k\to 0$ corresponds to $\lambda \to \infty$, which means that they are taking the infinite-wavelength limit of the function (along the $z$-direction). This makes the resulting function constant with $z$.  Since they do that, you can just set $z'=0$, since the function no longer depends on the $z$-coordinate.  (One likely has to take this limit carefully, but that's the general idea.)
We can get an idea for the physical meaning of this in the following way.  Suppose we want to somehow move smoothly from a 3D system to a 2D system. Let's consider the case of the electric field of a point charge, which is a fundamentally 3D situation. Then, let's "stretch" out the point charge so that's it smeared out over an infinitesimally thin line segment along the $z$-axis. The system remains as a 3D system, but the field changes as we do this. Now imagine stretching the line segment infinitely so that the charge is uniformly smeared out over the entire $z$-axis. In this case, the electric field now only varies with $x$ and $y$ and not with $z$ (that's a standard intro E&M problem). By taking any slice (so might as well take $z=0$), we've got an effective 2D field corresponding some kind of 2D point charge.
